# Numpy convert csv saved datetime64 back to datetime

Tags: python, numpy

I am not able to convert the saved datetime64 back to a timestamp and than back to `datetime.datetime.now()` format. I only get the error `ufunc 'subtract' cannot use operands with types dtype('<U18') and dtype('<M8[s]')`

To simplify for this post, I hard coded the first datetime64 into a list.

```py
    row = []
    row.append("1681903801863912.0")
    ts = (row[0] - numpy.datetime64(0, "s")) / numpy.timedelta64(1, "s")
    print(ts)
```

This is how the convertion from `datetime.datetime.now()` is happening.

```py
date64 = numpy.datetime64(datetime.datetime.now())
ret_val = numpy.insert(dates, 0, date64)
```

I already tried to load it back to a datetime64 object, but without any success.

Answer (score 1):

What you expect is unclear but you can convert string timestamp to `datetime64` with:

```
import numpy as np

arr = ['1681903801863912.0', '1682061528456548.0']
ts = np.array(arr, dtype='float64').astype('datetime64[us]')
```

Output:

```
>>> ts
array(['2023-04-19T11:30:01.863912', '2023-04-21T07:18:48.456548'],
      dtype='datetime64[us]')

>>> arr
['1681903801863912.0', '1682061528456548.0']
```